# jsPDF saving the file without extension when sent to nodejs/expressjs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jspdf, formidable

I have a class based react component that takes data from a user. The data is then fed to jsPDF.

```
let doc = new jsPDF();
doc.save()
```

This works fine. It saves the file with .pdf extension.

Now the problem is that I am sending this file to the express.js backend.

```
const pdf = new Blob([this.state.doc.output("blob")], {
        type: "application/pdf",
      });
```

OR

```
 const pdf = this.state.doc.output("blob");
```

NODE.js
I am using Formidable.js for receiving the file.

```
   const newPath = files.pdf.path;
```

The file gets saved without an extension.

I also did this

```
const newPath = `${files.pdf.path}.pdf`
```

This adds the .pdf to the string that is saved to mongodb, but the file saved is without any extension.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/issues/680

```
//front-end
const pdf = new File([doc.output("blob")], "myDoc.pdf", {
    type: "application/pdf",
});
```

```
//Node
const newPath = files.pdf.path;
```

Thanks to https://github.com/GrosSacASac